# is there a faster way to perform spell checking in atom?

Tags: atom-editor

right now i have to highlight the word that is underlined as misspelled, then double click it,  then choose  `correct spelling`, then choose the right word.
i am tired just writing all these steps,
any idea how to get this done faster?
I use vim plugin, so PLUS 1 for any solution that will let me avoid the trackpad/mouse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the **1.11.0-beta5** version of Atom, I had to register the spell-check keyboard shortcuts myself.

I put the following in my *keymap.cson* (Edit -> Keymap):

```
'.platform-darwin atom-text-editor':
  'cmd-:': 'spell-check:correct-misspelling'

'.platform-darwin .corrections atom-text-editor':
  'cmd-:': 'core:cancel'

'.platform-win32 atom-text-editor':
  'ctrl-:': 'spell-check:correct-misspelling'

'.platform-win32 .corrections atom-text-editor':
  'ctrl-:': 'core:cancel'

'.platform-linux atom-text-editor':
  'ctrl-:': 'spell-check:correct-misspelling'

'.platform-linux .corrections atom-text-editor':
  'ctrl-:': 'core:cancel'

'.corrections atom-text-editor[mini]':
  'enter': 'core:confirm'
  'tab': 'core:confirm'
```

Source: https://github.com/atom/spell-check/blob/master/keymaps/spell-check.cson

Answer (score 9):

By default, the keyboard shortcut `cmd-shift-:` (`ctrl-shift-:` on Windows) will quickly bring up a list of corrections when your cursor is on a misspelled word.